# UWP serial port communication for character write and read (UWP and Arduino)

Tags: c#, uwp, serial-port, win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core

I am using this code but not working  and throwing this exception:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object
devices[0] giving me null value.

```
   private async void ConnectToSerialPort()
    {
        string selector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM7");
        DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
        if (devices.Count > 0)
        {
            DeviceInformation deviceInfo = devices[0];
            SerialDevice serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);
            Debug.WriteLine(serialDevice);
            serialDevice.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialDevice.DataBits = 8;
            serialDevice.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.Two;
            serialDevice.Parity = SerialParity.None;

            DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(serialDevice.OutputStream);
            dataWriter.WriteString("your message here");
            await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
            dataWriter.DetachStream();
            dataWriter = null;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageDialog popup = new MessageDialog("Sorry, no device found.");
            await popup.ShowAsync();
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectToSerialPort();
    }
```

Please help me to remove this error please , i will very thankful to you .
please help :(

Comment: what line is the exception occurring on?

Comment: serialDevice  is giving null exceptions...

Comment: please edit your question to add that detail

Comment: sorry actually this line giving me exception:   serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);

Comment: If that is the line giving the exception then the issue is `deviceInfo` is null.  take a look at the `devices` array to see what it contains as item 0 is null.

Comment: please tell me solution for that :(

Comment: without sitting in front of your machine and debugging the code I cannot.  you have to provide us with the missing information (such as what you see in the `devices` array) - preferably by editing your answer to include that information.

Comment: devices giving me null.. (also edited)

Comment: lol, yes we established that.  *what is in the devices array?*  use the debugger and examine the contents of the array

Comment: debugging result of devices[0] is : {Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformationCollection}

Comment: that is the type of the object, yes - but *what are the items inside of the collection?*

Comment: Arduino, I have attached arduino with my laptop and want to serial communicate using this UWP applications, so devices[0] have arduino.

Comment: That is not what I am asking about at all.  Put a breakpoint in your code on that line.  Hover over the object `devices`.  Then *inside of Visual Studio* examine the contents of that collection to determine what is inside of it. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ab4z9u7Q_I) is a basic video explaining how to debug something using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 7):

You need add serial device capability in Package.appxmanifest like this:

```
<Capabilities>
    <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
      <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```

For more information you can reference [Serial device capability usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication).