# UWP SerialDevice Communication Property Access Error

Tags: c#, uwp, serial-port, serial-communication

I am attempting to communicate in UWP over serial ports. My problem is not connecting to the serial port, but rather reading the properties from the serial port and writing to the properties of the serial port. We have used the UWP samples **CustomeSerialDeviceAccess** and **Arduino** as well as our own UWP application, and in each we get the same errors. The first screenshot below was acquired by breaking on the **device.BaudRate = 9600** line and viewing the device properties. The 2nd screenshot was acquired when trying to read/write from/to the BaudRate property of the serial device.

I have not seen any other posts with the exact issue on UWP SerialDevice communication. Any assistance is much appreciated.

```
string selector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM3");
DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
         if (devices.Any())
         {
             DeviceInformation deviceInfo = devices.First();
             device = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);
             //*********************
             device.BaudRate = 9600;
             device.DataBits = 8;
             device.Parity = SerialParity.None;
             device.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
             device.ReadTimeout = device.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
             device.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;
         }
```

[image]

[image: Read Write Error]

Comment: Although it may not be related, you specify COM7 in the source code, but in the screen shot PortName is COM3. Is this correct?

Comment: @kunif sorry, typo.

Comment: If you have another COM port or USB to Serial cable, please try it.

Comment: @kunif I have an older WinForms application that accesses the data passed over the same COM port and cable just fine.

Comment: Many of the problems searched are due to lack of Package.appxmanifest. [Windows UWP...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024009/windows-uwp-windows-devices-serialcommunication-serialdevice-not-working), [UWP serial port...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467220/uwp-serial-port-communication-for-character-write-and-read-uwp-and-arduino), [UWP link to serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791149/uwp-link-to-serial-port), [UWPアプリでArduino...](http://shirotsuku.sakura.ne.jp/blog/?p=1369). For now, there is no other cause I can think of.

Comment: @kunif We have seen the Package.appxmanifest comments also and updated ours for serial communication.